# How can I combine two functions properly on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and I have the following lines of jQuery. My intention is 'on submit' to check if the input text values are filled and check to see if the radio buttons are checked or selected and make the text red if they aren't but i am not sure on how to combine the two.

Right now it is kind of buggy because it submits IF the text is filled and it ignores the radio buttons BUT it makes the text red before it submits. so it is working just not how I would like it to.

**jQuery**

```
$('#form3096').submit(function (e) {
    if (!$('#check-sm input:text').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value) != ""
    }).length) {
         $('.social-heading').css('color','red');

    }
});

   $('#form3096').submit(function(e) {
    if ($('input:radio', this).is(':checked')) {
        // everything's fine...
    } else {
        $('.radio-options').css('color','red');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to separate my validations into single units and combine them at the end. It makes it easier to read, maintain and test.

```js
$('#form3096').submit(function (e) {
  var isFieldPopulated, isRadioChecked;

  isFieldPopulated = $('#check-sm input:text').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.value) !== "";
  }).length > 0;

  if (!isFieldPopulated) {
    $('.social-heading').css('color','red');
  }

  isRadioChecked = $('input:radio', this).is(':checked');
  if (!isRadioChecked) {
    $('.radio-options').css('color','red');
  }

  return isFieldPopulated && isRadioChecked;
});
```

Comment: i like this method! @palpatim

Comment: do you have any reference on what you just did? i would like to know more on how i am able to write more effective jquery. especially like this! @palpatim

Comment: Not really any one reference--this is just the distillation of experience and fairly common coding practices. In this case: small units of functionality (I could have gone further by separating each validation into a standalone function, and making the value to be validated an argument to that function), and self-documenting code (by using local variables to indicate what is going on, and only resorting to comments to explain *why* something is happening). Hang out on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, you'll pick up a lot of good pointers

Comment: thanks i chose your answer! your code was better written than mine! @palpatim

Answer (score 2):

Call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the normal form submission.

```
$('#form3096').submit(function (e) {
    if (!$('#check-sm input:text').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value) != ""
    }).length) {
        $('.social-heading').css('color','red');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('#form3096').submit(function(e) {
    if ($('input:radio', this).is(':checked')) {
        // everything's fine...
    } else {
        $('.radio-options').css('color','red');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are using older IE version e.preventDefault will not work, instead use e.returnValue = false;

Comment: jQuery implements a polyfill.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$('#form3096').submit(function (e) {
    var len = $('#check-sm input:text').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value) != ""
    }).length;
    if (!len) {
         $('.social-heading').css('color','red');
         e.preventDefault();

    }
    if(!$('input:radio', this).is(':checked')){
         $('.radio-options').css('color','red');
         e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form3096').submit(function (e) {
    if (!$.trim($('#check-sm input:text').val()) {
         $('.social-heading').css('color','red');
         return false;
    }

    if ($('input:radio', this).is(':checked')) {
        // everything's fine...
        return true;
    } else {
        $('.radio-options').css('color','red');
        return false;
    }
});
```